# Row subsetting while preserving a label column in Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the data table with the ID/label first column like following;

```
         Name        P1  P2        P2
1:     DDX11L1 0.1300954  0 0.3019587
2:      WASH7P 2.0164780  0 0.6542439
3:   MIR6859-1 0.0000000  0 0.0000000
```

I often perform subsetting like this;

```
rowSums(dt[,!"Gene"]>1)>2
```

and this;

```
dt[,grepl(glob2rx("*CPM"), names(cladGE)), with=F]
```

These manipulations inevitably remove the first ID column.  I can do this with a data.frame with rownames setup but is there a data.table way to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the columns in `.SDcols` and use either `rowSums` and create a new column

```
dt[, newCol := rowSums(.SD > 1) > 2, .SDcols = 2:4]
```

Or `Reduce`

```
dt[, newCol := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `>`, 1)) > 2, .SDcols = 2:4]
```

---

If the columns are selected with some pattern attribute, the `grepl` can be used in the `.SDcols`

```
dt[, newCol := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `>`, 1)) > 2, 
          .SDcols = grepl(glob2rx("*CPM"), names(cladGE))]
```

Comment: @akrunThanks.   I actually wanted to create an new data.table off the subset so I did

Comment: @akh22  You can create a copy of original data `dt1 <- copy(dt)`  If it is intended to be new data without changing the original one, remove the `:=`.